# Static member variable not being initialized in Release - Compiler/clr bug?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, clr

Expected output & output I get in debug mode, and release mode under VS2010, .NET 4.0:

```
bar construct
main
```

Output in release mode ***not*** under the VS2010 debugger, and under WinDbg:

```
main
```

Program does not exhibit this behavior on VS2005, .NET 2.0

```
using System;

namespace static_init
{
    public class bar
    {
        public bar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bar construct");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static bar blah = new bar();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("main");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Probably related:
[Static constructor can run after the non-static constructor. Is this a compiler bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925611/static-constructor-can-run-after-the-non-static-constructor-is-this-a-compiler)

**Update**

In my actual code constructor `bar()` initializes some interop code with C++ (unmanaged).  It needs to happen before anything else in this library - is there any way to ensure that without putting in an `init()` function that touches all of the statics (with side effects that aren't externally referenced)  in the library?

Note for future searchers: I'm using SWIG, and this is an assumption that they made in their wrapper generation code.   `SWIGStringHelper` is the current offender, there may be more though.

**Conclusion**

Update to version 2.0 of SWIG, it puts in the static constructor as needed by newer version of .NET.

Comment: Thanks a lot for 'Update' and 'Conclusion' - I have very similar scenario and also used old SWIG 1.3.40 - just updated to 2.0.9 and all works fine. "Conclusion" save me a lot of time for investigation!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably getting optimized out because you don't use it.

It also isn't a compiler bug, it's in the language spec.

> **17.4.5.1** Static field initialization
>
> The static field variable initializers
>   of a class declaration correspond to a
>   sequence of assignments that are
>   executed in the textual order in which
>   they appear in the class declaration.
>   If a static constructor (§17.11)
>   exists in the class, execution of the
>   static field initializers occurs
>   immediately prior to executing that
>   static constructor. Otherwise, the
>   static field initializers are executed
>   **at an implementation-dependent time
>   prior to the first use of a static
>   field of that class**

Since you never use a static field of the Program class, the static initializer isn't guaranteed to run (though it could...the 'implementation-dependent time' above)

**Update**
You can accomplish what you want by making Program have a static constructor.

`static Program (){}`
or possibly by accessing another (possibly dummy) static variable

Answer (score 7):

Note that there have been some changes in .NET 4.0 regarding static initialization. Jon Skeet has written a blog post with some samples:

> **[Type initialization changes in .NET 4.0](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/)**

If you want precise initialization, you should use a static constructor (which may be empty).

```
using System;

namespace static_init
{
    public class bar
    {
        public bar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bar construct");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static bar blah = new bar();

        // This static constructor will make sure that the type Program 
        // is initialized before it is first used.
        //
        static Program()
        { }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("main");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```