# How does the CLR handles static classes?

Tags: c#, .net, static, clr, static-constructor

Can anyone explain how the CLR handles Static classes? Does the CLR create one singleton instance for handling static classes internally? If not, why do we have a static constructor in C#? (Per my understanding, we use constructors only for instantiating the class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all there is no static class in CLR. CLR doesn't know anything about static class.
It is the feature of C#.

Static classes are compiled into `abstract` as well as `sealed` class. Making it `abstract` prevent instantiation of it and `sealed` prevents inheritance.

Static classes are no special, it is just a simple class with all members static.

> Is, CLR internally creates one singleton instance for handling static
>   classes?

**No**, it is abstract and can't be instantiated.

> If not why we have an static constructor in C#?

Static constructor will be called when type is first referenced or instantiated. It is used to initialize the static members of the class.

[When is a static constructor called in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437352/when-is-a-static-constructor-called-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

The `static` constructor is called when the type is first referenced. It doesn't have to be a `static` class to have a `static` constructor.

The CLR doesn't create a singleton instance of a `static` class. It does keep the `static` variables in memory though after they are initialized.