# Why static constructor not called before first call to class method

Tags: c#, .net

According to Jon Skeet's artice [C# and beforefieldinit](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) and discussion in [When is a static constructor called in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437352/when-is-a-static-constructor-called-in-c) static constructor must be called before first call to a method of the class.

For some reason following code does not exhibit this behavior:

```
namespace AbstractAndStatic
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StaticClass.Equals(1,2);
            StaticClass.foo();
        }
    }
    static class StaticClass : Object
    {
        public static void foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Static");
        }
         static StaticClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("static constructor");
        }
    }
    class TestClass
    {
        public void deb()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Class Debug");
        }
    }
}
```

I am debugging the above code using the Visual Studio Debugger. When the statement `StaticClass.Equals(1,2);` gets executed in the Main method the static Constructor is not getting called but when `StaticClass.foo();` is executed it calls static constructor and then call the foo method.

I am little confused as why it didn't get called the the first time when executing `StaticClass.Equals(1,2);`.

Comment: I believe you need to override Object.Equals. As it stands, it's calling the base version. Every class inherits from object btw, so not necessary to do it manually.

Comment: Where is your Equals() method written?

Comment: @MicrosoftDN its inherited from `Object.Equals`

Comment: @RonBeyer: No, it's calling the `static Equals(Object, Object)` method.

Comment: @JonSkeet Figured that out about 30 seconds before you posted that :)

Answer (score 15):

Your call to `StaticClass.Equals` is *actually* just a call to [`Object.Equals(Object, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx), as `StaticClass` doesn't provide an applicable overload for `Equals`. If you look in the IL, you'll see that the compiler has resolved the call to just `Object.Equals(1, 2)`. If you're not calling a method which actually involves the static class, it doesn't need to be initialized.

Comment: Note that " it doesn't *need to* be initialized" - it would still be valid behavior if framework decides to call static constructor earlier.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: No it wouldn't. If a type has a static constructor, it's guaranteed that that is only executed *immediately* before the first reference to a member of that class. You may be thinking about when a type without a static constructor is initialized, which is considerably more lenient. Specifically, from the C# spec: "The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an application domain: An instance of the class type is created. Any of the static members of the class type are referenced."

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: See also: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet according to the C# PM that is actually not guaranteed (even if it is the current behavior): https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/33704 - for this guarantee module initializers should be used instead.

Comment: @OhadSchneider: I read your GitHub comment. I think there may be a miscommunication here, but I don't have time to look into it (or discuss it) right now.

Answer (score 0):

The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur :

**An instance of the class is created.**
**Any of the static members of the class are referenced.**