# Static Constructor is Never Called in C# / VB.Net Asp.Net Application

Tags: c#, vb.net, webforms

I have a static constructor that never gets called -
in fact CheckedIn is always set to true somehow
the code below is from my class library

```
    public partial class Commerce : DbContext
    {
...
        static Commerce()
        {
            CheckedIn = false;
            IsUpToDate = false;
            CheckSchema();
        }

        public static bool CheckSchema(Action<string,Exception> logMethod = null, bool force = false)
        {

            if (CheckedIn)
                return IsUpToDate;

            CheckedIn = true;
...
    }
```

the code below is a vb.net code behind page invoking the CheckSchema() method on the class above. When it calls, the constructor is never called:

```
        If (Commerce.Database.Model.Commerce.CheckSchema()) Then
            Return True
        End If
```

Comment: The static constructor is called once for a class. So has there been usages for "Commerce" before? Presumably yes it must have been instantiated.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your static constructor and fire up the app in a debugger.  Or, put in a `Console.WriteLine` (or `Debug.WriteLine`) call in it.  You will set it get called

Comment: [When is a static constructor called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437352/when-is-a-static-constructor-called-in-c)

Comment: If `CheckedIn` is set to true, then by definition the `CheckSchema` must have been executed (unless there is other code that sets that value to `true` that you haven't shown us). Also, this looks like a code smell to me anyway. Having anything static on a DbContext is inherently dangerous.

Comment: I have put a breakpoint on the constructor  - it never gets in.

Comment: It is possible that the break point is never hit, if the line was executed before debugger is attached.

Comment: If that's true, we'll need a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks! How can i close or delete a question? upon further debugging I realized I was calling the method in application_start in global.asax and since I was debugging it in IIS (not IIS Express) - the breakpoints were never hit

Comment: Write your findings as an answer and accept it. Others might run into the same issue and would welcome a hint as to where to look.