# Choose a random subclass of a class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Suppose I have a class `Letter` and a lot of classes `A`, `B`, ..., all of them inherit from `Letter`.

How can I choose a random child of `Letter`?

I know it sounds a bit broad, but what I want is something like this

```
public Letter GetRandomLetter()
{
    //return a random instance of A, B or any child class
}
```

The number of child classes is unknown so I can't just use some logic with random numbers to return an instance of each child class. I also don't want to use reflection.

Suppose there could be thousands of child classes and that if I come back 1 year later and want to create a new child class, nothing more than the class itself should be written in order for the method to keep working correctly.

Comment: Does `Letter letter = (Letter)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("A, AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.134, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"));` work for you?

Comment: You'll need to use reflection. Or you'll need a hard coded list of possible child types. Or you could assume that through some naming convention all types `A` through `Z` have been defined.

Comment: Once you have a `Type`, you could lean on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface#static-abstract-and-virtual-members to define a generic factory method on each type. Which you'll need to use reflection to call. But you can do all that work once, so you aren't using reflection every time the method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to find the matching derived classes in the same assembly as `Letter`, and then use expressions to build a factory for each of them. You should probably only call the `GetLetterFactories()` method once, and then cache the result:

```cs
public abstract class Letter
{

}

public class LetterA : Letter
{

}

private static IList<Func<Letter>> GetLetterFactories()
{
    Type letterType = typeof(Letter);
    var letterTypes = letterType.Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract && letterType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .ToList();

    var factories = new List<Func<Letter>>(letterTypes.Count);
    foreach (var type in letterTypes)
    {
        var constructor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        if (constructor is null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var newExpression = Expression.New(constructor);
        var convertExpression = Expression.Convert(newExpression, letterType);
        var funcExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Letter>>(convertExpression);
        factories.Add(funcExpression.Compile());
    }
    return factories;
}
```

Usage:

```
var factories = GetLetterFactories();
Letter letter = factories[Random.Shared.Next(factories.Length)]();
```

Note: this will ignore any subclasses without a parameterless constructor. It can be adapted if parameters are required.

Comment: Answer is good for ingenuity but terrible for performance.  Upvoted though because it does what the OP asks - obtains as many classes as possible that implement an interface, and then returns a random one of them.

Comment: @csharpforevermore It's not necessarily "terrible for performance." If you're constantly creating new random instances of `Letter`, then caching factories at application start is better in the long run. That's what I've assumed here, from the details OP provided. If OP just needs to instantiate a random `Letter` once in a blue moon, then simply caching the types and using `Activator.CreateInstance` might yield acceptable performance during create, and incur less of a performance hit during application startup.  It really depends where OP needs it to be fast.

Comment: Short of some kind of analyser to automatically generate something like Enigmativity's answer when the rest of the code is built, I think these are the best options you're going to have in terms of performance, short of hard coding a factory for each one into a list, which goes against what OP wants.

Comment: Yeah I agree but reflection IS bad for performance, especially as he is describing possibly "thousands" of classes.
BTW I upvoted not downvoted. I think you're being trolled TBH with the downvotes when people do that and don't state why.

Comment: @csharpforevermore Yeah, I do agree that reflection is bad for performance. That's why I aim to make it a one-time performance hit wherever I can when I need to use it. I do appreciate that you upvoted. I'm not sure why I got downvoted for a legitimate answer to the question, to be honest. I know there's no obligation for people to state _why_, but it would be nice if people did, you know?

Answer (score 4):

Given a collection of `Func<Letter>`, calling a random function is easy. But how would you build a collection of these functions based on the types in an assembly?

For these types of problems I find it useful to write a generic helper function, then call it via reflection;

```cs
private static Func<Letter> GetDelegate<T>() where T : Letter, new()
    => () => new T();

var getDelegate = new Func<Func<Letter>>(GetDelegate<Letter>)
    .Method
    .GetGenericMethodDefinition();

factories = typeof(Letter).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t != typeof(Letter) 
        && !t.IsAbstract 
        && t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(Letter)))
    .Select(t => (Func<Letter>)getDelegate
        .MakeGenericMethod(t)
        .Invoke(null, null))
    .ToArray();
```

While this approach does use reflection, it's a one-off cost. Store the collection in a static field, and using these methods should be as efficient as a collection that was manually defined.

If you need to pass a standard set of arguments to a constructor, I would lean on [static abstract members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface#static-abstract-and-virtual-members)

```cs
public interface ILetter<T> where T : ILetter<T>
{
    static abstract T Factory(int argument);
}

private static Func<int, Letter> GetDelegate<T>() where T : Letter, ILetter<T>
    => (arg) => T.Factory(arg);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simplest approach to do what you want

```
var factories = new Func<Letter>[]
{
    () => new A(),
    () => new B(),
    () => new C(),
};

Letter letter = factories[Random.Shared.Next(factories.Length)]();
```

Comment: This is similar to my own solution but there are 2 drawbacks that I'm trying to avoid: If there are hundreds of classes, this would be a big pain to write and if I want to add a new child class in the future, I would have to remember to add it there.

Comment: This is a good example for me and since the poster omitted so much information, I have upvoted this answer.  It's the only answer to a poorly described question.  I disagree with Daniel's "this is like my answer" since not once does he mention Func usage.  
The fact he says there could be thousands of classes shows that this is most likely poorly designed solution.

Comment: @Daniel: Some variation of this is the right answer as far as I'm concerned. If you need code to create hundreds of different classes, then you'll need to write them out anyway. And as far as if you add a new class, you'd need to do the same for any other approach as well. The one exception I can think of is to use reflection to find all the classes in the app that derive from the base class in question. This would automatically detect new such classes. But such an approach would be less efficient than this one. But I doubt the entire approach of having all those classes is the best path.

Answer (score -3):

Create a `List<Type>` with all the letters, and select random from it using the `Random` class. If you need an instance of the letter, create a new one, or if not, then change return type to `Type`.

Give `Letter` a static `List<Type>`, then you can also give the letter class a static constructor that adds its own type to the list (unless it’s the base class) to the list using `typeof(this)`.

I *might* have said something stupid because I’m relatively new to c# (only a couple months in), but I think that would work.

Here’s an example letter class

```cs
class Letter 
{
    public static List<Letter> Letters = new();

    static Letter() 
   {
        Type type = typeof(this);
        if (type != typeof(new Letter())
        {
             Letters.Add(type);
        }
   }
}

public Letter GetLetter() 
{
    Random random = new();
    return new Letter.Letters[random choice];
}
```

Comment: It's a good start, the same start I took, but it has the drawbacks I mentioned in Enigmativity answer.

Comment: If you add the static constructor in the base class letter, all children would have it, so all of them would add themselves without you having to write it (unless I’m misunderstanding static constructors) except for in the letter class.

Comment: at what moment they would add themselves? I'm guessing I would have to iterate over them to have them added into this static list and this is the whole problem.

Comment: I think static constructors are run when the program starts, so they are going to be added at the beginning. I added potential code for that (just edited) 
Also, here’s the Microsoft docs for static construction: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors

Comment: Each `Type` is initialised, and their own static constructor executed, on first use. You would need an additional method to force each static constructor to execute. However that won't help, since `Letter` would only be constructed once, so your `Letters` list would only include `typeof(Letter)`. Your code won't even compile, since `this` is only accessible in an instance method.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! Static constructors are a new concept to me.

Comment: @Jewels static constructors are called just before the class is used for the first time (an instance created, or static members accessed/referenced). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1437372/3181933)

Comment: Did anyone test this code? It doesn't work. It's full of syntax errors. `typeof(this)` is not valid C#. `typeof(new Letter())` is not valid C#. `Letters.Add(type);` is adding an item of the wrong type to the list.

Comment: @Daniel - this code is patently wrong. Why have you accepted it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).