How can I call abstract static methods through an interface?
I am looking for a better way than reflection to call static methods on a bunch of classes.
Consider that I have a factory that is seeded as such:
private static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Type> buildableTypes =
  typeof(IBuildable).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IBuildable)))
    .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract)
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t);

And consider that IBuildable is like this:
public interfact IBuildable
{
  static abstract bool IsBuildable(string params);
}

I would like to get all of the types that are buildable given the current params.
var currentlyBuildableTypes = buildableTypes.Values
    .Where(t => /* t.IsBuildable(params) */); // not sure what goes here

I would like to avoid instantiating every class, as there could be a decent number.  I could pretty easily do this via reflection, but given the new static abstract interfaces in C# 11, I was hoping there would be a more elegant manner in which I could approach this.  Note that in this case, using generics doesn't seem to be an option, either, as I won't know the type until runtime.

You've just gotta use reflection here. Dynamic dispatch of static abstract methods only work on generic type parameters.

IMHO write a generic helper function. Use .MakeGenericMethod and reflection to call it. eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/78111556/4139809

@JeremyLakeman I had thought of that too, but will that be substantially faster than just finding IsBuildable in each type? AFAIK most of the cost comes from the MethodInfo.Invoke call, not from finding the method with GetMethod.

I wasn't suggesting to use reflection for each call to IsBuildable, but to create a delegate (or an entire helper instance) you can use to repeatedly call it.

As others have mentioned, you can only really make use of the static abstract interface member if it is part of a generic constraint like so:
public static bool IsBuildable<T>(string parameter) where T : IBuildable => T.IsBuildable(parameter);

But you can use the static interface member as a guarantee that a type that is assignable to IBuildable will have a static method IsBuildable. You can then create a delegate for each IsBuildable method like so:
private static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<string, bool>> buildableTypes =
  typeof(IBuildable).Assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IBuildable)))
    .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract)
    .ToDictionary(
      t => t.Name,
      t => t.GetMethod(nameof(IBuildable.IsBuildable), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).CreateDelegate<Func<string, bool>>());

Note here that I have replaced your IsSubclassOf with IsAssignableTo as the first won't work for interfaces. The dictionary values are now Func<string, bool> allowing you to easily call the IsBuildable function of a type with buildableTypes[typeof(...)](myParameter).

That's the right approach. And even performant with the cast to Func<>. For possible private interface implementations one might add BindingFlags.NonPublic

@lidqy that should not be necessary as static abstract interface members are not actually part of the interface and cannot be explicitly implemented. So the implementation is always public static on the class that implements the interface

AT least in .NET 8 in you can do (relating to the interface in the OP): static bool IBuildable.IsBuildable(string @params) {/* impl */} Then you'd need the NonPublic flag and also to prepend the interface name in GetMethod("IBuildable.IsBuildable", ...). But okay I admit it's likely a rare option.

Interesting I did not know that. If you want to handle explict interface implementations you have to add NonPublic and also add the full name of the interface before the method name (e.g. MyNamespace.IBuildable.IsBuildable)

Sometimes you just need to introduce a few more types.
public interface IBuildable
{
    static abstract bool IsBuildable(string parms);
}
public abstract class BuildHelper
{
    public abstract Type Type { get; }
    public abstract bool IsBuildable(string parms);
}
public class BuildHelper<T> : BuildHelper
    where T : IBuildable
{
    public override Type Type 
        => typeof(T);
    public override bool IsBuildable(string parms)
        => T.IsBuildable(parms);
}
private static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, BuildHelper> buildableTypes =
   // TODO, left as an exercise for the reader


This is just moving the problem down the line. In the "exercise for the reader" part, you still need to create many BuildHelper<T>s, which would involve calling its constructor with reflection, unless I am missing something.

I guess this is potentially faster if IsBuildable needs to be called multiple times,. I had assumed otherwise.

Sure, you'll have to use either .MakeGenericMethod() to call another helper function, or .MakeGenericType() to Activator.Createinstance. You can't really avoid reflection completely, but you can make sure you only pay for it once per Type.

Not only will I be calling this many, many times, but this is just one of multiple methods I will likely want.  I may just turn this whole thing into a factory of factories - having a bunch of singletons that each wrap around the actual type constructors. Then the inner factories can handle the Is* methods with actual inheritance and such as well.

Mine is just an extension to @a-ctor's solution, covering also the private interface implementation issue.
See sample at : https://dotnetfiddle.net/496bLV
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Func<string, bool>> buildableTypes =
             typeof(IBuildable).Assembly.GetTypes()
             .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && t.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IBuildable)))
             .ToDictionary(
               t => t,
               t => (t.GetMethod(nameof(IBuildable.IsBuildable), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public) ?? 
               t.GetMethod($"{nameof(IBuildable)}.{nameof(IBuildable.IsBuildable)}", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)).CreateDelegate<Func<string, bool>>());
        
        // dummy code to show it works
        var i = 1;
        foreach (var kv in buildableTypes) {
            var type = kv.Key;
            var isBuildableFunc = kv.Value;
            Console.WriteLine("IsBuildable in {0}: {1}", type.Name, isBuildableFunc.Invoke("test" + (i++ * 5)));
        }
    }
}

public interface IBuildable
{
  static abstract bool IsBuildable(string @params);
}

public class B1 : IBuildable
{
    // public "normal" interface implementation
    public static bool IsBuildable(string @params) =>
       (@params?.Length ?? 0) % 2 == 0;
}

public class B2 : IBuildable
{
    // private interface implementation
    static bool IBuildable.IsBuildable(string @params) =>
       (@params?.Length ?? 0) % 2 == 0;
}

